# Unable to click on multiple links on a webpage in selenium webdriver with java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

**My Code**

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("https://google.com");
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("selenium");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@value='Search']")).click();

List<WebElement> alllinks = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[3][@class='_NId']/div/div/div/h3"));

for(WebElement cl:alllinks)
{
    System.out.println(cl.getText());

    if(cl.getText()!="")
    {
        cl.click();
    }

}
```

By above code i am not getting any exception but also i am not able to click on any link on a webpage, I just want to click on every link one by one.Please tell me the solution how to do this, Thanks in advance.

Comment: click and then what you do?

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption of opening all links is correct but the code could not show you the desired output as

1> When google results are shown for 'Selenium' keyword, you have many links over  there. So if you manually click on every link - it opens in the same tab by which the other links will not be accesible as WebDriver gives you `org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException:`exception.

Now try this code :

```
        open some driver
        driver.get("https://google.com");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("selenium");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@value='Search']")).click();

        List<WebElement> alllinks = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[3][@class='_NId']/div/div/div/h3"));

        for(WebElement cl:alllinks)
        {
            System.out.println(cl.getText());
            if(cl.getText()!="")
            {
                Actions action = new Actions(driver); // I have added these lines
                action.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).moveToElement(cl).click().perform();
                action.keyUp(Keys.CONTROL).perform();
            }
         }
```

So now all links will be opened in a new tab and it works .

Comment: no but it is also not working. doesn't give any exception.

Comment: Is the browser opening up? If yes where did it get stuck?

Comment: yes browser is opening up and curser is navigating to each and every link but didn't click

Comment: Add some wait time before click() method